# insert a content of integers array to the vector of QString

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, vector, qstring

I want to insert the content of array of integers :
`int arr[n]` to the vector of QStrings. `std::vector<QString> vQString`.- I can do it by inserting the array`s elements one by one :

```
vQString.push_back(QString::number(arr[i]));
```

By I prefer to do that using one insert operation - any advices?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Qt but according to the docs for [QString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html) it doesn't support such operations.

Comment: According to the official documentation, you can't do this in one line. you can add values one by one. write a function and call it in one line.

Comment: Any reason you're using std::vector instead of QVector? It's certainly not wrong... but normally you adopt Qt-style containers like QVector unless you're working with external interfaces or libs that make that too annoying. Here's a good link to compare them: http://blog.codeimproved.net/2009/12/qtl-or-stl/

Comment: Just to clarify, are you appending to existing vector or want to copy it over to a new vector?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a 1-line solution. But is an extendable solution. What you basically do is create a template function to do the conversion for you in an exception-safe manner, like below:

```
namespace yournamespace {
    template <typename U>
    struct NumberToString {
        QString operator()(const U& val) {
            return QString::number(val);
        }
    };

    template <typename T, typename U, typename Convertor>
    void CopyArrayToVector(QVector<T>& dst, const U* src, const size_t size) {
        QVector<T> temp;
        temp.reserve(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            temp.push_back(convert(src[i]));
        }
        dst.swap(temp);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using yournamespace;
const size_t n = 10;
int *arr = new int[10];
QVector<String> dst;
CopyArrayToVector<QString,int,NumberToString<int> >(dst, arr, n);
```

**DISCLAIMER**: I'm not familiar with Qt framework. I whipped this up by looking at their documentation. Please feel free to correct me for any errors.

Comment: It appears from the usage of push_back() that they want append, not replace... although they're calling it insert.

Comment: @darron: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant in your comment :S. Are you saying I should have it as `temp.insert()` instead of `temp.push_back()`?

Comment: The "dst.swap(temp)" line is removing whatever entries were in dst to start with. Using the += overload probably matches the intention better.

Comment: @darron: The function is called 'CopyTo' not 'AppendTo' :).. Of course, if that's his use-case, he can definitely create another function to do so.

Comment: True... but that's your function name, not his. Anyway, I just meant to point out that 'CopyTo' doesn't appear to be what he's asking... even if it is trivial to convert it. Not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int n = 5;
int arr[n] = { 4, 6, 2, 3, 1 };
vector< QString > v( n );

transform( arr, arr + n, v.begin(),
           [] ( int i ) { return QString::number( i ); } );

for ( const QString& str : v ) {
    cout << qPrintable( str ) << endl;
}
```

Slightly cheating...!  Just use a `for` loop like everyone else.